# What's the best way to display a blown-up image using minimal JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Goal:

- On mouseover (or :hover), enlarge the preview image by about 400% and display it in the center of the page
- Remove the preview when the mouse leaves

The Problem:

- Solutions like FancyBox are too bloated

  - in FancyBox's case it ignores width and height for image elements, which makes it useless
- Most of these "lightboxes" steal focus when they're called

Really, I'm just looking for a simple, efficient solution.

Comment: It would be great if you can adjoin some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this. the trick is `position` you can put the div wherever you want.
read something [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). and you can read about hover [here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

here is an html example. (copy this to a text file and open it withyour browser)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <title>Test</title>
      <script text="text/javascript" 
          src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.js">
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="">Lynx</li>
      <li>Jaguar</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="picture" style="position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;">
    </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var animal = {
        "Lynx": 
          "http://wnbaoutsiders.files.wordpress.com/2009/06/lynx21.jpg",
        "Jaguar" : 
          "http://www.tropical-rainforest-animals.com/image-files/jaguar.jpg"
      }
    var hovered = function(e) {
      //you can get what to show from the elemnt, instead of the content
      // you could use an id.
      var name = $(e.target).html()
      $('#picture').append("<img src='" + animal[name] +"'/>")
    }
    var unhovered = function() {
      $('#picture').empty();
    }
    //here you bind mouseenter and mouseleave
    $('li').hover(hovered, unhovered);
  </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for a tooltip? You can use any html (including images) inside the tooltip.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html